# Share variables between files in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

Here are 2 files:

```
// main.js
require('./module');
console.log(name); // prints "foobar"

// module.js
name = "foobar";
```

When I don't have "var" it works. But when I have:

```
// module.js
var name = "foobar";
```

name will be undefined in main.js.

I have heard that global variables are bad and you better use "var" before the references. But is this a case where global variables are good?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a variable from a file to another file in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612011/how-to-get-a-variable-from-a-file-to-another-file-in-node-js)

Answer (score 233):

Global variables are *almost* never a good thing (maybe an exception or two out there...). In this case, it looks like you really just want to export your "name" variable.  E.g.,

```
// module.js
var name = "foobar";
// export it
exports.name = name;
```

Then, in main.js...

```
//main.js
// get a reference to your required module
var myModule = require('./module');

// name is a member of myModule due to the export above
var name = myModule.name;
```

Comment: global variables are bad - I totally agree with that. But I could be, that the module has a dependency to a variable. Is there a way to pass this variable to the other js-file via the require function?

Comment: @jjoe64 Not sure I follow what you mean. You can effectively share any value you want through the `exports` object.

Comment: The OP is asking whether a variable can be defined in the main.js, and then used in module.js. I have the same requirement to define paths that are used over and over again.

Comment: @Designermonkey In that case you're probably better off having a config object with those types of values that can also be require()'d into a given file.  Note that you *can* just do `global.foo = 'bar'` and then access `foo` anywhere you'd like... but like I said in my original answer, that is *almost* never a good thing.

Comment: Why are global variables bad? If I want to treat a module as an object
is there any better way to store that object's propoerties/attributes?

Comment: @designermonkey how did you do that, please elaborate?

Comment: It was 10 years ago. I have no idea now. I suspect it was like the answer above.

Answer (score 65):

I'm unable to find an scenario where a global `var` is the best option, of course you can have one, but take a look at these examples and you may find a better way to accomplish the same:

### **Scenario 1: Put the stuff in config files**

You need some value that it's the same across the application, but it changes depending on the environment (production, dev or test), the mailer type as example, you'd need:

```
// File: config/environments/production.json
{
    "mailerType": "SMTP",
    "mailerConfig": {
      "service": "Gmail",
      ....
}
```

and

```
// File: config/environments/test.json
{
    "mailerType": "Stub",
    "mailerConfig": {
      "error": false
    }
}
```

(make a similar config for dev too)

To decide which config will be loaded make a main config file (this will be used all over the application)

```
// File: config/config.js
var _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = _.extend(
    require(__dirname + '/../config/environments/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.json') || {});
```

And **now you can get the data** like this:

```
// File: server.js
...
var config = require('./config/config');
...
mailer.setTransport(nodemailer.createTransport(config.mailerType, config.mailerConfig));
```

### **Scenario 2: Use a constants file**

```
// File: constants.js
module.exports = {
  appName: 'My neat app',
  currentAPIVersion: 3
};
```

And use it this way

```
// File: config/routes.js

var constants = require('../constants');

module.exports = function(app, passport, auth) {
  var apiroot = '/api/v' + constants.currentAPIVersion;
...
  app.post(apiroot + '/users', users.create);
...
```

### Scenario 3: Use a helper function to get/set the data

Not a big fan of this one, but at least you can track the use of the 'name' (citing the OP's example) and put validations in place.

```
// File: helpers/nameHelper.js

var _name = 'I shall not be null'

exports.getName = function() {
  return _name;
};

exports.setName = function(name) {
  //validate the name...
  _name = name;
};
```

And use it

```
// File: controllers/users.js

var nameHelper = require('../helpers/nameHelper.js');

exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
  var user = new User();
  user.name = req.body.name || nameHelper.getName();
  ...
```

There could be a use case when there is no other solution than having a global `var`, but usually you can share the data in your app using one of these scenarios, if you are starting to use node.js (as I was sometime ago) try to organize the way you handle the data over there because it can get messy really quick.

Comment: I liked Scenario 2, but can these values be changed after we talk build? like most often we do, npm run build.

Or do you know some way to be able to change values after build?

Comment: @KashifUllah not sure if I'm able to answer your comment just with the provided info, you may want to add a new question in the site

Answer (score 30):

If we need to share multiple variables use the below format

```
//module.js
   let name='foobar';
   let city='xyz';
   let company='companyName';

   module.exports={
    name,
    city,
    company
  }
```

Usage

```
  // main.js
    require('./modules');
    console.log(name); // print 'foobar'
```

Comment: just a quick note to left out confusion that can arise at first spot: module.exports is what should be used! whatever your js file is called (ex: global.js). module is a node object that exist in the global scope! [so within global.js we use module.exports=.....]

Comment: it will success if you remove the 'let', and there is no need to the "module.exports.."

Comment: is there a way to update values from `module.js` (e.g name, city, company) in all files that import it, so that the updated values are accessible to all files that have imported it?  is there something like a 'dynamic global variable' that can be accessed and edited by whatever module references it?    i have [a question with more context here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185112/how-to-define-all-socket-io-io-onconnection-logic-outside-of-app-js-in-a-sep).

Answer (score 8):

Save any variable that want to be shared as one object. Then pass it to loaded module so it could access the variable through object reference..

```
// main.js
var myModule = require('./module.js');
var shares = {value:123};

// Initialize module and pass the shareable object
myModule.init(shares);

// The value was changed from init2 on the other file
console.log(shares.value); // 789
```

On the other file..

```
// module.js
var shared = null;

function init2(){
    console.log(shared.value); // 123
    shared.value = 789;
}

module.exports = {
    init:function(obj){
        // Save the shared object on current module
        shared = obj;

        // Call something outside
        init2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

a variable declared with or without the var keyword got attached to the global object. This is the basis for creating global variables in Node by declaring variables without the var keyword. While variables declared with the var keyword remain local to a module.

see this article for further understanding - https://www.hacksparrow.com/global-variables-in-node-js.html

Comment: Do these fragments contradict? 1) "a variable declared with or without the var keyword got attached to the global object." and 2) "variables declared with the var keyword remain local to a module."

Answer (score 3):

Not a new approach but a bit optimized. Create a file with global variables and share them by `export` and `require`. In this example, Getter and Setter are more dynamic and global variables can be readonly. To define more globals, just add them to `globals` object.

global.js

```
const globals = {
  myGlobal: {
    value: 'can be anytype: String, Array, Object, ...'
  },
  aReadonlyGlobal: {
    value: 'this value is readonly',
    protected: true
  },
  dbConnection: {
    value: 'mongoClient.db("database")'
  },
  myHelperFunction: {
    value: function() { console.log('do help') }
  },
}

exports.get = function(global) {
  // return variable or false if not exists
  return globals[global] && globals[global].value ? globals[global].value : false;
};

exports.set = function(global, value) {
  // exists and is protected: return false
  if (globals[global] && globals[global].protected && globals[global].protected === true)
    return false;
  // set global and return true
  globals[global] = { value: value };
  return true;
};
```

examples to get and set in any-other-file.js

```
const globals = require('./globals');

console.log(globals.get('myGlobal'));
// output: can be anytype: String, Array, Object, ...

globals.get('myHelperFunction')();
// output: do help

let myHelperFunction = globals.get('myHelperFunction');
myHelperFunction();
// output: do help

console.log(globals.set('myGlobal', 'my new value'));
// output: true
console.log(globals.get('myGlobal'));
// output: my new value

console.log(globals.set('aReadonlyGlobal', 'this shall not work'));
// output: false
console.log(globals.get('aReadonlyGlobal'));
// output: this value is readonly

console.log(globals.get('notExistingGlobal'));
// output: false
```

Answer (score 1):

With a different opinion, I think the `global` variables might be the best choice if you are going to publish your code to `npm`, cuz you cannot be sure that all packages are using the same release of your code. So if you use a file for exporting a `singleton` object, it will cause issues here.

You can choose `global`, `require.main` or any other objects which are shared across files.

Otherwise, install your package as an optional dependency package can avoid this problem.

Please tell me if there are some better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If the target is the browser (by bundling Node code via Parcel.js or similar), you can simply set properties on the `window` object, and they become global variables:

```js
window.variableToMakeGlobal = value;
```

Then you can access this variable from all modules (and more generally, from any Javascript context).