# How to get a variable from a file to another file in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Here is my first file:

```
var self = this;
var config = {
    'confvar': 'configval'
};
```

I want this configuration variable in another file, so I have done this in another file:

```
conf = require('./conf');
url = conf.config.confvar;
```

But it gives me an error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'confvar' of undefined

What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share variables between files in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922994/share-variables-between-files-in-node-js)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

### Edit (2020):

Since *Node.js version 8.9.0*, you can also use ECMAScript Modules with varying levels of support. [The documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

- For Node v13.9.0 and beyond, experimental modules are enabled by default
- For versions of Node less than version 13.9.0, use `--experimental-modules`

> Node.js will treat the following as ES modules when passed to node as the initial input, or when referenced by import statements within ES module code:
>
> - Files ending in `.mjs`.
> - Files ending in `.js` when the nearest parent `package.json` file contains a top-level field `"type"` with a value of `"module"`.
> - Strings passed in as an argument to `--eval` or `--print`, or piped to node via STDIN, with the flag `--input-type=module`.

Once you have it setup, you can use `import` and `export`.

Using the example above, there are two approaches you can take

#### ./sourceFile.js:

```
// This is a named export of variableName
export const variableName = 'variableValue'
// Alternatively, you could have exported it as a default. 
// For sake of explanation, I'm wrapping the variable in an object
// but it is not necessary. 
// You can actually omit declaring what variableName is here. 
// { variableName } is equivalent to { variableName: variableName } in this case. 
export default { variableName: variableName }
```

#### ./consumer.js:

```
// There are three ways of importing. 
// If you need access to a non-default export, then 
// you use { nameOfExportedVariable } 
import { variableName } from './sourceFile'
console.log(variableName) // 'variableValue'

// Otherwise, you simply provide a local variable name 
// for what was exported as default.
import sourceFile from './sourceFile'
console.log(sourceFile.variableName) // 'variableValue'
```

#### ./sourceFileWithoutDefault.js:

```
// The third way of importing is for situations where there
// isn't a default export but you want to warehouse everything
// under a single variable. Say you have:
export const a = 'A'
export const b = 'B'
```

#### ./consumer2.js

```
// Then you can import all exports under a single variable
// with the usage of * as:
import * as sourceFileWithoutDefault from './sourceFileWithoutDefault'

console.log(sourceFileWithoutDefault.a) // 'A'
console.log(sourceFileWithoutDefault.b) // 'B'

// You can use this approach even if there is a default export:
import * as sourceFile from './sourceFile'

// Default exports are under the variable default:
console.log(sourceFile.default) // { variableName: 'variableValue' }

// As well as named exports:
console.log(sourceFile.variableName) // 'variableValue
```

You can re-export anything from another file. This is useful when you have a single point of exit (index.`{ts|js}`) but multiple files within the directory.

Say you have this folder structure:

```
./src
├── component
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── myComponent.js
│   └── state.js
└── index.js
```

You could have various exports from both store.js and my-component.js but only want to export some of them.

#### ./src/component/myComponent.js:

```js
import createState from "./state";
export function example(){ };
```

#### ./src/component/state.js:

```js
export default function() {}
```

#### ./src/component/index.js

```js
export { example as default } from "./myComponent";
export * from "./myComponent"
```

#### ./src/index.js

```js
export * from "./component"
```

---

### Original Answer:

You need [module.exports](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/all.html#modules):

> Exports
>
> An object which is shared between all instances of the current module
> and made accessible through require(). exports is the same as the
> module.exports object. See src/node.js for more information. exports
> isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.

For example, if you would like to expose `variableName` with value `"variableValue"` on `sourceFile.js` then you can either set the entire exports as such:

```
module.exports = { variableName: "variableValue" };
```

*Or* you can set the individual value with:

```
module.exports.variableName = "variableValue";
```

To consume that value in another file, you need to `require(...)` it first (with relative pathing):

```
const sourceFile = require('./sourceFile');
console.log(sourceFile.variableName);
```

Alternatively, you can deconstruct it.

```
const { variableName } = require('./sourceFile');
//            current directory --^
// ../     would be one directory down
// ../../  is two directories down
```

If all you want out of the file is `variableName` then

#### ./sourceFile.js:

```
const variableName = 'variableValue'
module.exports = variableName
```

#### ./consumer.js:

```
const variableName = require('./sourceFile')
```

Comment: can you include call the variable witouth requiring it?, what happens if you have a lot of files that must include the same variables or modules? do I have to use require for all? is there a global declaratiion in a main file so we can use them in all other files?

Comment: Can you use `import` in the consuming file?

Comment: I noticed in the documentation that they do `exports.variableName = "variableValue";` instead of `module.exports.variableName = "variableValue";` .

Which is the preferred way? Why are there 2 ways of doing it?

Comment: @Tomiwa https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383925/48266

Answer (score 11):

#### File *FileOne.js*:

```
module.exports = { ClientIDUnsplash : 'SuperSecretKey' };
```

---

#### File *FileTwo.js*:

```
var { ClientIDUnsplash } = require('./FileOne');
```

This example works best for React.

Comment: This didn't work for me (`ClientIDUnsplash` was undefined in FileTwo.js). This worked instead: `const ClientIDUnsplash = require('./FileOne');`