# In node.js, using mysql-simple-pool how do I share pool with all modules?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get a db.js file that will basically hold 1 connection pool that all my other models which access a database can require and use.

My current code for db.js:

```
var Pool = require('mysql-simple-pool');

var mysql_pool = new Pool(50, {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'game'
});

//I used this line to try and init the pool, it didn't work :)
//mysql_pool.query("USE game", function(){});

exports = mysql_pool;
```

Then, in my model I say:

```
var pool = require('./models/db.js');

pool.query('select * from user where id = ', [user_id], function(err, rows) {
...
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'query' at Strategy._verify
```

Is there a better way?  Is there a way to make this possible?  :) Do I need to add more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
exports = mysql_pool;
```

That should be:

```
module.exports = mysql_pool;
```

The reason for this is explained [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383925/893780), but in short, you're basically doing this:

```
var module = { exports: {} };
var exports = module.exports;

...
exports = mysql_pool; // wrong! you're just reassigning the `exports` variable,
                      //        but that won't change `module.exports`

return module.exports;
```

After you require your module, `module.exports` is still the empty object, hence the error.

Comment: wow, and here I thought it was a real error, just turns out i'm a noob :).  Thank you, works perfectly now.