# Importing vs Requiring with Babel in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to import a class inside one file:

```
"use strict";
import models from "../model";
class Foo {
    bar() {
    }
}
export default new Foo();
```

It works when I use import, like:

```
import Foo from "./foo";
console.log(Foo.bar); // [Function bar]
```

The problem is that doing it with require gives me undefined:

```
var Foo = require("./foo");
console.log(Foo.bar); // undefined
```

and the Foo variable seems to be an empty class. Why is that so? What's going on?

Comment: You are using Babel to transpile this right?

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Comment: You can drop the `"use strict"` when using ES6 modules

Comment: Never export singleton instances of a class. Either export the whole class, or just create the singleton module as an object literal.

Comment: [Please use the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Becmascript-6%5D+require+default+export).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### TL;DR

This is because importing with `import` is different than `require`. When you import a module with the syntax `import X from "Y"`, the default export is automatically imported, as the syntax is meant to import the default export by specification. However, when you `require`, the default export is *not* automatically imported like you'd expect. You must add `.default` to get the default export with `require` like: `require("./foo").default`.

#### Babel Transpilation

Take a look at how [Babel transpiles](https://babeljs.io/repl) some example code:

```
export { x }
```

Becomes:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.x = x;
```

This makes sense as `x` is just exported normally. Then you would proceed to do:

```
require("module").x;
```

To receive `x`. Similarly, try the following:

```
export default new Foo();
```

That becomes:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = new Foo();
```

You'll see that the default export is attached to the `exports` object as a property named `default`, just as `x` was exported with property `x`. That means, to get the default export with `require`, you'll need to do:

```
require("module").default;
```

Now to explain the why it's `undefined`. In the line:

```
var Foo = require("./foo");
```

`Foo` here is actually just an object with a `default` property:

```
{
    default: //Whatever was exported as default
}
```

Thus, trying to do `Foo.bar` will yield `undefined` because there is no `bar` property. You need to access the `default` property to access your instance.

You might think this is a little clunky, and other do too. That's why [there's a plugin](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) to get rid of the need for the extra `.default`. The plugin does `module.exports = exports["default"]` to assign the `module.exports` from ES5, to `exports["default"]`.<sup>1</sup>

#### Difference Between `import` and `require`

For `import` syntax, Babel does the following transpilation:

```
import Foo from "./foo";
Foo.bar();
```

Becomes:

```
"use strict";

var _foo = require("./foo");

var _foo2 = _interopRequireDefault(_foo);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

_foo2.default.bar();
```

To break it down line by line, Babel just `require`s the module. Then, it calls `_interopRequireDefault` on the module. A check is done with `obj && obj.__esModule` to make sure that the module actually exports anything and the module is exported with ES2015/ES6 syntax. If it is, then the module is returned as is, or else `{ default: obj }` is returned. This is to ensure that `module.exports = x` in ES5 is treated the same as `export default x` in ES2015/ES6.  You'll notice that for default import syntax, Babel automatically adds `.default` to retrieve the default export.

However, the corresponding code with `require`:

```
var Foo = require("./foo");
Foo.bar();
```

Is completely valid ES5 code, so nothing is transpiled. Consequently, `.default` is never added to `Foo` when it is used. Thus, the default export is not retrieved.

---

#### Notes

<sup>1</sup>It should be noted that `module.exports` and `exports` just refer to the same object, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383925/5647260). `module.exports` holds the data which is exported from the module. The reason why `module.exports = x` successfully exports `x` as default and does not need the extra `.default` on `require` is because you're assigning the `module.exports` to one single thing. Since `module.exports` holds the data that's imported, `require("module")` imports whatever `module.exports` is, which is `x`. If `module.exports` were 3, then `require("module")` would be 3. If `module.exports` were an object like `{ blah: "foo" }`, then `require("module")` would be `{ blah: "foo" }`. By default, `module` and `module.exports` are objects.

One the other hand, `exports.default` exports an object (that refers to the same object as `module.exports`) with a `default` property that holds the default export. You may want to do `exports = x` to export `x` as default but since `exports` is assigned a reference to `module.exports` this will break the reference and `exports` will no longer point to `module.exports`.