# Why does this NPM package say it is not a constructor?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on a Sails.js project that requires me to use [this NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-rules-engine). I created a new Sails.js service to invoke this package after `npm install`-ing it like this:

```
// Require and initialize the rules engine
var jsonRulesEngine = require('json-rules-engine'),
    rulesEngine = new jsonRulesEngine();
```

When I run this script, I get the following error:

```
/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:61
        fn = function () { throw arg; };
                           ^

TypeError: jsonRulesEngine is not a constructor
    at Object.verify (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/api/services/RulesService.js:21:27)
    at Object.wrapper [as verify] (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
    at /Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/api/controllers/UtilsController.js:113:43
    at /Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/api/services/RedisService.js:55:13
    at tryCatcher (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise.successAdapter [as _fulfillmentHandler0] (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeify.js:23:30)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:566:21)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/Nag/Code/learn-nodejs/server/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31)
    at runCallback (timers.js:666:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:611:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Any clue why I might get that error? In the examples section of the package, the owner of the package imports the package using ES6 format whereas I am requiring it. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @AndrewLi Tried your suggestion but now it says `TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`.

Comment: @AndrewLi I made a mistake by calling it like var Engine = require('json-rules-engine').Engine();`. Your  original comment was correct. Happy to mark it as an answer if you add it as is.

Comment: I was wrong, the `Engine` *is* exported by default. I've edited the answer to reflect the real reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you require an NPM package, depending on your module system<sup>1</sup>, the default export *will not automatically be imported when you do this*:

```
var jsonRulesEngine = require('json-rules-engine');
```

So when you require like you did, it will return the module object, not necessarily the *default* export as expected. In the package `json-rules-package` the `Engine` *is exported by default* but your require doesn't require the default. If you log the returned module object it will look like this:

```
{
  Engine: function(...) { ... },
  Fact: function(...) { ... },
  Operator: function(...) { ... },
  Rule: function(...) { ... },
  default: function(...) { ... }
}
```

The engine is under the property `default` *and `Engine`*. You could do:

```
var jsonRulesEngine = require('json-rules-engine').default();
```

Or:

```
var jsonRulesEngine = require('json-rules-engine').Engine;
```

The first will explicitly import the default export. Then you can create an instance of the class like so:

```
var rulesEngine = new jsonRulesEngine();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> **Yes, using ES2015 `import` will affect the outcome**. If you were to use `import` syntax from ES2015, this problem would not be encountered. To know why see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42475844/5647260). In short, Babel transpiles ES2015 code so that `default` is explicitly accessed when requiring thus importing the default export.