# Assign value to exports in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

For emxaple in these line of code below:

```
const fs = require('fs')
```

We get the object in `module.export`, not the object in `exports` of fs module.

But inside Express code, I see some assignment to `exports` like below, **I do not know the purpose of it and this is my question**

```
exports.application = proto;
exports.request = req;
exports.response = res;
```

Please help to let me know if you have any ideas about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "module.exports" and "exports" in the CommonJs Module System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383795/difference-between-module-exports-and-exports-in-the-commonjs-module-system)

Comment: If this is `req` and `res` from a particular http request, then this code is probably wrong or at best a very bad design.  You would have to show us a lot more context for us to help you further.

Comment: I just want to focus on assignment to export purpose, I can thing the request and response in the code is “whatever”.

Answer (score 2):

exports and module.exports refer to the same thing (exports is a reference to module.exports), unless you reassign exports by doing `exports=foo`. Nodejs always exports `module.exports` so as long as you do not reassign `exports` to something else, `exports.bar=foo` and `module.exports.bar=foo` have the same effect.