# why exports returns undefined however module.exports returns the right data

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a `database.js` file. in this file i have 3 functions named `connect`, `getDb` and `disconnect`. 
when i use `exports` (the below code) , the `require` function loads nothing! and when i use module.exports, every thing goes in the right way! whats wrong with `exports` here?

```
// my database.js file

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const database_name = 'car-repair';
const uri = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${database_name}`;

let database;

const connect = () => {
  let options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  };

  try {
      MongoClient.connect(uri, options, (err, db) => {
          database = db;
          console.log('connected to database.');
      });
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
  }
};

const getDB = () => database;

const disconnect = () => database.close();

exports = {
    connect, getDB, disconnect
};
```

if i use the code like the below, it returns `undefined`

```
// my app.js file
const database = require('./database');

console.log(database.connect); // undefined!
```

when i change the `exports` to `module.exports` everything works properly.

```
module.exports = {
    connect, getDB, disconnect
};
```

whats wrong with `exports`?

Comment: By itself, `exports` would be a variable. Maybe you are mistaking it as the ES6 syntax with `export` or `export default` ?

Comment: @seblor have you seen the code? i have not used es6 `default`. review the code i have written at the top. (database.js)

Comment: There is a lot of good info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383795/difference-between-module-exports-and-exports-in-the-commonjs-module-system

Comment: @Mahdi yes I have read your code. And my comment was asking if maybe you were mixing the 2 syntaxes...

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez thanks. this is the right answer :)

Comment: @Seblor the `exports` is a variable that references to `module.exports`. if we change it completely, the reference will be changed and it will not set values to `module.exports` any more.

Comment: What do you mean "exports is a variable that references to module.exports" ? I don't see any `const exports = module.exports` anywhere in your code. Again, by itself, `exports` would be a variable. `exports` is not a keyword.