# Why does "exports" and "module.exports" behave differently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I know that "exports" and "module.exports" are functionally identical.

But I found that when they actually run under the same conditions, they produce different results.

I found this difference applying the internal module pattern to my project.

Below is a brief example code for situations in which differences have occurred.

**modules.js ("exports" Ver)**

```
const calsum = require("./calsum"),
    calculator = require("./calculator");

exports.calsum = calsum; // this is "exports" Ver
exports.calculator = calculator; // this is "exports" Ver
```

Only the 4th and 5th lines of the modules.js will be changed and the other js files are all under the same conditions. "exports" is used in this modules.js

**modules.js ("exports.module" Ver)**

```
const calsum = require("./calsum"),
    calculator = require("./calculator");

exports.modules = {calsum, calculator}; // this is "export.modules" Ver
```

"exports.module" is used in this modules.js

**calsum.js**

```
function sumit(a,b) {
    return a + b;
} 

module.exports = {sumit};
```

**calculator.js**

```
const modules = require("./modules");

class Calculator { 

constructor() {}

calSum(a,b) {
    let total = modules.calsum.sumit(a,b);
    return total;
    }
}

module.exports = {Calculator}
```

**index.js**

```
const modules = require("./modules"); // modules = { 'calsum' : sumit(function), 'calculator' : Calculator(obj) }

let myObj = new modules.calculator.Calculator();

console.log(myObj.calSum(2,4));
```

When I run index.js, the one using "exports" works correctly.

But using "module.exports" causes TypeError.

I just guess that when myObj.calSum(2,4) was called in and entered the scope, the modules property could not be loaded properly.

I don't know why.

It must be the same code functionally, but why does this difference occur?

I couldn't find an answer even after thinking for a long time.

I want you to share your knowledge with me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "module.exports" and "exports" in the CommonJs Module System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383795/difference-between-module-exports-and-exports-in-the-commonjs-module-system)