# module.export vs export handler in js and typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services

what is the difference between this exporting function in typescript

```
    export const handler = someWrapper(
    eventHandler({
            ...someMiddlewares,
            lambdaHandler
    })
)
```

and this exporting in javascript:

```
                module.export ={ 
                  someWrapper(
                     eventHandler({
                    ...someMiddlewares,
                    lambdaHandler
                }),
              )
           lambdaHandler
          }
```

Comment: The first one is an ECMAScript module, and the second one is a CommonJS module

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Difference between “module.exports” and “exports” in the CommonJs Module System](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383925/11910438)

> `module` is a plain JavaScript object with an `exports` property. `exports` is a plain JavaScript variable that happens to be set to `module.exports`.
> At the end of your file, node.js will basically 'return' `module.exports` to > the `require` function. A simplified way to view a JS file in Node could be this:
>
> ```
> var module = { exports: {} };
> var exports = module.exports;
>
> // your code
>
> return module.exports;
> ```
>
> If you set a property on `exports`, like `exports.a = 9;`, that will set `module.exports.a` as well because objects are passed around as references in JavaScript, which means that if you set multiple variables to the same object, they *are* all the same object; so then `exports` and `module.exports` are the same object.
> But if you set `exports` to something new, it will no longer be set to `module.exports`, so `exports` and `module.exports` are no longer the same object.