# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined at exports.getTodos (/home/jk/Documents/webPractice/todoapp/helpers/helpers.js:5:13)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Here is my helper code**
*this is the file that causes an error while trying to exprot get.Todos to the index.js file it works fine while inserting datas to mongo database but kept showing these erros while trying to access the data from the database using find() method *

```
    const db = require('../model'); 

    exports.getTodos = function(req, res){
        db.Todo.find()
        .then(function(foundTodo){
            res.json(foundTodo)
        }).catch(function(err){
            res.send(err);
        })
    }
    exports.createTods = function(req, res){
        db.Todo.create(req.body)
        .then(function(newTodo){
            res.json(newTodo); 
        }).catch(function(e){
            res.send(e);
        })
     }
     exports.getTodo = function(req, res){
        db.Todo.findbyId(req.params.todoId)
        .then(function(foundId){
            res.json(foundId)
        }).catch(function(err){
            res.send(err);
        })
    }
    exports.updateTodos = function(req, res){
        db.Todo.findOneAndUpdate({_id : req.params.todoId}, req.body,{new:true})
        .then(function(updateddata){
            res.json(updateddata);
        }).catch(function(err){
            res.send(err);
        })
    }
    exports.deleteTodo = function(req, res){
        db.Todo.remove({_id:req.params.todoId})
        .then(function(){
            res.json({message:"Removed"}); 
        }).catch(function(err){
            res.send(err);
        })
    }

    module.exports = exports;
```

**here's my model**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

const todoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type : String, 
        required : true
    }, 
    completed :{
        type:Boolean, 
        default:false
    }, 
    date_Created : {
        type:Date, 
        default: Date.now
    } 
  
}); 

const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema); 


module.exports = Todo; `
```

Comment: could you attach your model file

Comment: already done attached the model

Comment: Know about what is the difference between `Module.exports` and `exports` and how to use them correctly. See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383795/difference-between-module-exports-and-exports-in-the-commonjs-module-system