# The requested module './server/controller/controller.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am currently new at backend and using `ES6 modules` in my project

when I import controller file to `index.js` and start the project it says :-

Syntax Error: The requested module './server/controller/controller.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

and when I import it as :-

```
import {controller} from './server/controller/controller.js'
        ^^^^^^^^^^
Syntax Error: The requested module './server/controller/controller.js' does not provide an export named 'controller'
```

so what i am doing wrong here
i also mention "type": "module" in my package. json file

index.js file

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import path from 'path';
import mongoose  from "mongoose";
import {controller} from './server/controller/controller.js'
import route from './server/routes/route.js';
const __dirname = path.resolve();
const app = express();

//mongoDb
const connectDB = async () => {
    try{
        // mongodb connection string
        const con = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        })

        console.log(`MongoDB connected `);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);

    }
}
//mongodb finish




dotenv.config({path:'confige.env'})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

//database
connectDB()

//view engine
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : true}))
app.set("view engine", "ejs")


app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/css")))
app.use('/js', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/js")))

//routes
app.use('/',route)
// routes finish

//controller 
app.post('/api/users',controller.create)
app.put('/api/users',controller.update)
app.delete('/api/users',controller.delete)
app.get('/api/users',controller.find)


app.listen(PORT, ()=> { console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)});
```

controller.js file

```
import Userdb from "../model/model.js";

exports.create = (req,res) =>{

}
exports.find = (req,res) =>{

}
exports.update = (req,res) =>{

}
exports.delete = (req,res) =>{

}
```

model.js file

```
import  mongoose  from "mongoose";
const scheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    gendr:String,
    status:String
})
const Userdb = mongoose.model('userdb',scheme)
export default Userdb
```

should i need to replace exports in controller.js with Userdb beacause i am using ES6 module ?
and if so than what will be the code of controller.js file

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Basically you need to export *controller* from the controller.js file to make use of the controller functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of exports in ES6: name exports(one or more) and default(one per module).

Named exports are helpful when you have more than one thing to export from the modules and in your case I think you use use it.

In your server.js file, you are using destructing in the import, however, you are not exporting in the form of object which has `controller` key in it.

In your controller.js:

```
import Userdb from "../model/model.js";

const create = (req,res) =>{

}
const find = (req,res) =>{

}
const update = (req,res) =>{

}
const _delete = (req,res) =>{ }

export {create, find, update, _delete}
```

In your index.js :

```
import { create, find, update, _delete } from 'controller.js';
```

I suggest you to check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) link, how import and export works in ES6.

Comment: Yes that's the what i am doing wrong finally got that after spending whole days

Comment: and i also want to ask is there any diffrance between export and exports in comman JS module

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383795/difference-between-module-exports-and-exports-in-the-commonjs-module-system) link.

Comment: `delete` cannot be a variable name