# Identifier from require() is reported as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in node.js. I have two files.

winston.js:

```
class Winston {
    constructor(count) {
        this.count = count
    }
}
```

start.js

```
const winston = require('./winston')
let myWinston = new Winston(1)
```

when I run the start.js,(node ./start.js)

I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: Winston is not defined
```

Any one know how I should include the Winston file?

Comment: Try this [How to get a variable from a file to another file in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612011/how-to-get-a-variable-from-a-file-to-another-file-in-node-js)

Comment: First: You're instanciating Winston (Title case), and you are importing winston (lowercase). Second: you need to export the class from winston.js

Answer (score -1):

winston.js:

You didn't export Winston class.

```
export.defaults = class Winston {
    constructor(count) {
        this.count = count
    }
}
```

start.js

You should use the result of require, not Winston.

```
const winston = require('./winston')
let myWinston = new winston(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Look closely for the caps `W` in `Winston`

```
// start.js
const Winston = require('./winston')
let myWinston = new Winston(1)
```

and you need to [`export default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export) in the other file

```
// winston.js
export default class Winston {
    constructor(count) {
        this.count = count
    }
}
```