# How to construct new class using ES6 syntax from library module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

**index.js of imported npm module `myLib`**

```
const Mod1 = require('./mod1');
const Mod2 = require('./mod2');
const Mod3 = require('./mod3');

module.exports = {
  Mod1,
  Mod2,
  Mod3,
};
```

**mod1.js**

```
class Mod1 {
  constructor(url) {
  }
}
```

**file using the above npm module**

```
const Mod1 = require('myLib');
const instance = new Mod1();
```

This is throwing the following error when trying to run it:

```
const instance = new Mod1();
                ^
TypeError: Mod1 is not a constructor
```

How should I reference the class from a single import `index.js` so that I may be able to create an instance of the class?

Comment: how do you export in `mod1.js`?

Comment: the require statement should properly include Mod1, otherwise you should use `export default Mod1;`. To properly import your module, use: `const { Mod1 } = require('path_to_mylib');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a variable from a file to another file in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7612011/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a slight mistake in your import, the actual import will be like:

```
const {Mod1} = require('myLib');
```

which will pull the class from the file and give it to you (ES6 feature)

you can also do it like:

```
const Mod1 = require('myLib').Mod1;
```

hope this helps.