# How to export a variable from a module in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, module

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922994/share-variables-between-files-in-node-js) we know that variables can be exported from one module in JavaScript:

```
// module.js
(function(handler) {
  var MSG = {};

  handler.init = init;
  handler.MSG = MSG;

  function init() {
    // do initialization on MSG here
    MSG = ...
  }
})(module.exports);
```

---

```
// app.js
require('controller');
require('module').init();
```

---

```
// controller.js
net = require('module');

console.log(net.MSG); // output: empty object {}
```

Those above codes are in `Node.js` and I get one `empty object` in my `controller.js`. Could you please help me figure out the reason of this?

**Update1**

I have updated the above codes:

```
// module.js
(function(handler) {
  // MSG is local global variable, it can be used other functions
  var MSG = {};

  handler.init = init;
  handler.MSG = MSG;

  function init(config) {
    // do initialization on MSG through config here
    MSG = new NEWOBJ(config);
    console.log('init is invoking...');
  }
})(module.exports);

// app.js
require('./module').init();
require('./controller');

// controller.js
net = require('./module');
net.init();
console.log(net.MSG); // output: still empty object {}
```

**Output**: still empty object. Why?

Comment: You are overwriting the local variable, not the `handler` property. If you must, do assign to `hander.MSG`, but it would be better to just extend the existing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `console.log(net.MSG)` in controller.js, you have not yet called `init()`. That only comes later in app.js.

If you `init()` in controller.js it should work.

---

Another issue i discovered through testing.

When you do `MSG = {t: 12};` in `init()`, you overwrite `MSG` with a new object, but that doesn't affect `handler.MSG`'s reference. You need to either set `handler.MSG` directly, or *modify* `MSG`: `MSG.t = 12;`.

Comment: I found another reason. Edited.