# Vue & Laravel: Access and use eventHub

Tags: laravel, vue-component, vue-resource, vue.js

In resources/assets/js/**app.js** I have created `eventHub` Vue instance:

```
require('./bootstrap');    

var eventHub = new Vue();

Vue.component('todos-list', require('./components/todos/TodoList.vue'));
Vue.component('todos-add', require('./components/todos/TodoAdd.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

How can I use it in components that are created in separate **.vue** files?

For example, I also have two components:

- **todos-list** located in /components/todos/**TodoList.vue**, which is used to fetch the data from server-side using vue-resource:

  ```
  <template id="todos-list-template">
  <div>
      <ul v-if="todos.length > 0">
          <li v-for="todo in todos">
              {{ todo.title }}
          </li>
      </ul>

      <p v-else>You don't hanve any Todos.</p>
  </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  export default {
      template: '#todos-list-template',
      data() {
          return {
              todos: {}
          }
      },

      mounted() {
          this.$http.get('api/vue/todos').then(function(response) {
              this.todos = response.data;
          });
      },

      methods: {
          handleAddedTodo: function(new_todo) {
              this.todos.push(new_todo);
          }
      },

      created: function() {
          eventHub.$on('add', this.handleAddedTodo);
      },

      destroyed: function() {
          eventHub.$off('add', this.handleAddedTodo);
      }
  }
  </script>
  ```
- **todos-add** located in /components/todos/**TodoAdd.vue** which is used to add (save) the new '*todo*' using vue-resource:

  ```
  <template id="todos-add-template">
  <div>
      <form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewTodo()">
          <div class="form-group">
              <input v-model="newTodo.title" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a new Todo">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <button>Add Todo</button>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  </template>


  <script>

  export default {
      template: '#todos-add-template',
      data() {
          return {
              newTodo: { id: null, title: this.title, completed: false }
          }
      },

      methods: {
          addNewTodo() {
              this.$http.post('api/vue/todos', { title: this.newTodo.title }).then(function(response) {
                  if (response.status == 201) {
                      eventHub.$emit('add', response.data);
                      this.newTodo = { id: null, title: this.title, completed: false }
                  }
              }, function(response) {
                  console.log(response.status + ' - '+ response.statusText);
              })
          }
      }
  }
  </script>
  ```

When I add (save) new '*todo*' using the **todos-add** component (*TodoAdd.vue*) - I want to update data in **todos-list** component. If I understood well the documentation - for component communication we need to use centralized event hub. And that's what I tried - but I am getting the following error:

> eventHub is not defined

I guess because it is defined in **app.js**, but how can I use in components that are created in separate **.vue** files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `eventHub` is actually not defined where you are using it. You have to export this from **app.js** and import in **TodoAdd.vue**.

in app.js:

```
var eventHub = new Vue()
exports.eventHub = eventHub
```

Add this code in TodoAdd.vue:

```
<script>
import eventHub from '/path/of/app'
export default {
    template: '#todos-list-template',
```

This should make `eventHub` availble in `TodoAdd.vue`.

---

### Edited

As the comment suggests, you may consider using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html), as you have data whcih is being used across components, and going forward I see chances of getting it more complex, more event handlers and event listerners, which can quickly become a nightmare to manage.

Comment: You may want to look at a tutorial for vuex though for managing state.

Comment: @saurabh **1.** Can you explain what `exports.eventHub = eventHub` means, what do you do with that? **2.** My second question is about importing: Since in **app.js** we already require all of these components, can importing of app.js cause some problems since we use Laravel Elixir (Gulp/Webpack) to compile all of these into one file? (in app.js we require these components, and in components we import app.js)

Comment: @PeraMika http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922994/share-variables-between-files-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

```
var eventHub = new Vue()
```

You are getting this error because eventHub is actually not defined where you are using it. You have to export this from app.js file.  Use this one

```
window.eventHub = new Vue()
```