# Converting data in .js file to json

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm currently working on a project that involves referencing the entire Pokemon pokedex, and as I was looking around for sources, I realized that Pokemon Showdown is open source and as a result, there's a full pokedex in the repository. However, when I opened up the file that contains the [pokedex](https://github.com/Zarel/Pokemon-Showdown/blob/master/data/pokedex.js) I found that it's not set up as a json file, but as something else entirely.

So, here are my questions:
1: What exactly is the data stored as? An array of objects?
2: How can I either convert the data to JSON or reference it as I would JSON(using key names)

Comment: The entire JSON/ Object of Objects in this case is exported into a variable `BattlePokedex`. Maybe you should have a look at [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922994/share-variables-between-files-in-node-js) to understand how exports work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I ended up not converting it to json but just leaving it as an object in a separate file. For those with a similar problem in the future, just do the following:

If your object is in a separate file, add a script import to your html *before* your script import for the main javascript(it's the same way you would import jquery). Then change the `.exports` line to a variable declaration. For me it looked like this before:

`exports.BattlePokedex = {`

I then changed it to this:

`var dex = {`

To access the different variables, I used this line of code:

`var pokemon = dex[name];`

Answer (score 1):

The data is a JavaScript object which is exported as a [module](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/) for external files to use. What you can do is to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the object to JSON string.

```
const battlePokedex = require('data/pokedex.js');
const pokedexInJson = JSON.stringify(battlePokedex);

console.log(`Now it's the JSON representation of the JS object ${ pokedexInJson }`)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Data is stored as JavaScript object the key is the *name* of each pokemon
2. See below

Delete code below from the file and change the file name to `.json` and you get your JSON data.

```
'use strict';

exports.BattlePokedex =
```

Comment: So it's stored as JS object? Oh, looks to me like JSON array

Comment: JS array is like `[{}, {}, {}]`. This is a object `{key: {}, key: {}}` or dictionary in other languages sense.

Comment: No problem, if this solve your question please accept the answer. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a module that exposes an object with all the pokedex data. You can import this module and it will return the data you want as an object. Here is a small example:

```
var pokedex = require('./pokedex.js'); //Path to file where is the module you want to import
```

For instances, imagine you want to get the data from Pikachu:

```
// pokedex is the module you imported, BattlePokedex is what they exposed 
// in the module, and the pikachu is the object containing the pikachu data
var pikachu = pokedex.BattlePokedex.pikachu;
```

I hope this helps but if you could give more context (pieces of code for instance) I can try and give a more complete answer.

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(...)`

Comment: @jhearst are you using node modules? and another question, are you using ecmascript 5 or ecmascript 6?

Comment: I'm not using node(I'm planning on hosting the page on github.io)