# Getting undefined on an exported variable in my protractor tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

While running my `protractor` tests , I came up with this scenario, where I had to export a variable from one of my POM file to another. For example, let us suppose `file.js` is the file where the variable is defined as

`file1.js`

```
var xy = some_random_8chars;
 ...
 ...
module.exports={

//other module exports

exportvar1 : xy
}
```

Now, I need to import this in my `file2.js` to access the value of `xy`. So I'm doing this in my `file2.js`

```
var ximport = require('file1.js');

var use_new_value = ximport.exportvar1;

console.log(use_new_value) ;
```

As per my understanding, this should be printing `some_random_8chars`. However my console shows `undefined`, which I am failing to understand. Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try using [this sytax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

```
export {exportvar1} //in file1

import { exportvar1 } from 'file1'; //in file 2
```

Comment: I think this would not work with var. Quoting this from the same link you posted- *that it is not possible to use var, let or const with export default*.

Comment: Oops you are correct. I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922994/share-variables-between-files-in-node-js) may be of more use to you.

Comment: Yeah. I went through this link, but I'm still getting the undefined error.

Comment: Is where you are declaring xy out of scope of your export statement?

Comment: If you try to console.log(xy) right before you export your variables does it print out as undefined? Or does it print the value you want to be in it?

Comment: it print's out the value of the variable correctly. However, I did the console.log post the export, and then I get an undefined.