# Node.js run file inside another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

this is my current code

```
function includeClass(classname, ctx) {
   var txt = fs.readFileSync("socket.io/" + classname + ".js");
   return txt;
}

//define globals here
var _PLAYERS = {};
var _SPAWNPOINTS = [];

vm.runInThisContext(includeClass("vector"));
vm.runInThisContext(includeClass("class"));
vm.runInThisContext(includeClass("connectionHandler"));
vm.runInThisContext(includeClass("game"));
```

But that way, class.js file can't access variables from global scope or other files. because now i get errors like, `_PLAYERS` or `require` is undefined. I've tried `eval()` too, but it didn't do anything at all.

How can I run these js scripts in main script so they get interpreted as 1 whole?

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922994/share-variables-between-files-in-node-js

Comment: @ttulka thats very ugly way of achieving overall goal, especially setting constants like __dirname and require or other functions. I can't believe there is no way of just binding two files into 1, its an interpreted language anyways!

Answer (score 0):

https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_options:

> Running code does not have access to local scope, but does have access to the current global object.

Your `_PLAYERS` variable is not truly global, it is local to your script. As well as some other variables (like `require`) which are also in the [module scope](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_scope).

You can try to assign the needed variables to `global` object, however, I am not well aware what side effects and complications may follow.