# Share variables between files in Node.js loading late?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am following the Example listed out by: [Share variables between files in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922994/share-variables-between-files-in-node-js)

main.js:

```
var name = "foobar";
exports.name = name;
var Login = require("./Scripts/file");
```

file.js:

```
 const file = require('./../main.js');
 var name = file.name;
 console.log("result: "+name);
```

output:

```
result: undefined
```

when I adjust file.js:

```
const file = require('./../main.js');
var name = file.name;

setInterval(function(){
    console.log("result: "+name);

},1000/30);
```

output:

```
result: foobar
```

It looks like the variable is being passed late? how do I prevent this?

Comment: What's the point of this circular import? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: You have a circular `require()` where A loads B and B loads A.  Can't do that in node.js.   One of the `requires()` will end up not getting its exports because of the circularity.

Comment: Exporting variable from main.js to file.js. Program entry point is main.js So i am using require to ensure that file.js is running also but it also needs variable passed to it from main.js. I assume this is not good programming?

Comment: Move common dependencies to a 3rd file so that A loads C and B loads C.  This breaks the circular dependency.